# How to make the custom info window visible without click in google map android?

Tags: android, google-maps

Already i did, whenever click the marker can able to show the custom info window in the map. But here, have to be know how to visible custom info window for the particular latlong marker without click on it.

Thanks in Advance.. :)

Comment: marker.showInfoWindow()

Answer (score 1):

You can show the info window of any marker directly without clicking on it.

- You can directly call the `marker.showInfoWindow();` to show the info
  window and also you can call `marker.hideInfoWindow();` to hide the window.
- You can also create a custom window by making `InfoWindowAdapter` interface and then call `GoogleMap.setInfoWindowAdapter()`
- You can also make these info window have some event on it
  ([example](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-samples/blob/master/ApiDemos/java/app/src/main/java/com/example/mapdemo/MarkerDemoActivity.java))

More about info windows [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/infowindows)

Comment: Thanks Akshay for your Nice examples. But based on latitude and longitude which I passed from previous activity.  I have to show custom infowindow without click that marker when opening the google map,